# FUSE python issues

Tags: python, fuse

I am trying to learn Fuse. First thing I did was to test helloFS.py located at `/usr/share/doc/python­fuse/examples/`. I installed FUSE from its source and python bindings from [Fusepy](https://github.com/terencehonles/fusepy).
First I was getting this error `ImportError: cannot import name Fuse`. I changed it to FUSE. Now I am getting another error `your fuse-py doesn't know of fuse.__version__, probably it's too old`. I am not getting this. I also tried `sudo apt-get install python-fuse`.
Did I install wrong libraries?How should I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your python search path (sys.path), and make sure it's actually importing the correct fuse library.  It's possible you're picking up an old version from somewhere.

Also note that fuse-python is not the same as fusepy.They have different APIs, so if you are writing to one API and including another, you'll have issues.  I prefer fusepy, myself, but you should probably pick one and stick with it.

Comment: Yes. the problem was `fusepy`. I uninstalled it and continued my work with `python-fuse`. Thanks